# WCF custombinding mutualcertificate keep getting 'The request message must be protected' error

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, x509certificate

i have a server with wcf soap services. With simple httpbinding configuration everything worked perfectly. 
After I changed the web.config to custombinding I keep getting the same error :

The request message must be protected. This is required by an operation of the contract ('IMyServices','http://tempuri.org/'). The protection must be provided by the binding ('BasicHttpBinding','http://tempuri.org/').

This is my web.config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004" />
          <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" requireDerivedKeys="false"
            messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
          <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="false" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" name="NewWCF.MyServices">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
          name="wsHttpMembershipEndpoint" contract="NewWCF.IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://10.130.111.111/NewWCF" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <certificate findValue="CN=Central-Gateway" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
              <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck" 
        certificateValidationMode = "None"/>
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=MySrvTst" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceSecurityAudit serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure"
            messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

lang-xml -->

Both certificates appear correctly in mmc.exe

I try to test it through a browser calling .svc path , should it work that way or does it fail because of the certificates ?

Is there a way to see a more detailed error?

What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Brian.

Comment: Have you checked that Protection level on the binding? or service Contract?Maybe there is a mismatch there

Comment: Enable exceptions on server side,this will give you detailed error.